# extjs 4 combobox , How to disabled tab and enter key

Tags: extjs4

I am using extjs 4.0.7. I want to disabled tab and Enter key event when user using Combobox. I have tried to use keyUp and KeyDown event. But I didn't get any alert for it.

Here is my code:

```
{
  xtype: 'combo',
  store: ds,
  id:'UserBO_SelectComponentId',
  displayField: 'displayName',
  valueField: 'userId',
  typeAhead: false,
  hideLabel: true,
  disabled: false,
  hideTrigger:true,
  multiSelect:true,
  delimiter: ";",
  anchor: '100%',
  triggerAction: 'all',
  listeners: {
     change: function( comboField, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ){
       selectUserCallBack2(newValue,'UserBO_SelectComponentId',comboField,oldValue);
     },
     select:function(comboField,oldValue){
        testRec(comboField,oldValue)
     },
     keypress:function(comboField,e){
        disabledKeysOnKeyup(comboField,e)
     }
  },
  listConfig: {
     loadingText: 'Searching...',
     enableKeyEvents: true,
     emptyText: 'No matching posts found.'
  }, 
  pageSize: 10 
}
```

Can anyone please suggest what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyup, keydown and keypressed events only fire if enableKeyEvents is set to true. Default this is set to false, so you need to add `enableKeyEvents:true` to the combobox config. And then do special treatment for enter and tab key.

Comment: I now see you used that enableKeyEvents in the list config, that config is for ext.view.Boundlist, you need to use it directly on the combobox config

Comment: I've made this example for you http://jsfiddle.net/nscrob/jZkHp/24/, to show you how to handle tab and enter events, however tab event causes combo to lose focus, so you should try to do a workaround to avoid that.

Comment: ohh, Thanks its working for me. Actually my requirement is on either tab or Enter combox should be stay ideal ,i.e. on key press it should not select any option. Can i achive this ? As i have done return false but still not working

Comment: i think you are looking for this option http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-autoSelect, set this to false and nothing will be selected on enter or tab, until you highlight it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to listen to key events and tab into that. What you want to do is set `autoSelect` to false. It's true by default. When set to false the user has to manually highlight an item before pressing the enter or tab key to select it (unless the value of typeAhead were true), or use the mouse to select a value.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-autoSelect