# How to prevent opening all windows in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

In my extjs system I can open all windows using **tab** key and **enter** key in the key    board. How can I stop this. I used `modal:true`, but still can open all windows indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

The keyup, keydown and keypressed events only fire if enableKeyEvents is set to true. You need to add enableKeyEvents:true. Check this: [extjs 4 combobox , How to disabled tab and enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630667/extjs-4-combobox-how-to-disabled-tab-and-enter-key)

Comment: Thank you but i'm not need to disable key events actually i need to focus only the  child elements only.